# Create view based on stored procedure or create table with it's results

Tags: google-bigquery

I wrote some code and i want to create view based on it or create table with it results.
The problem is that i completely don't have any idea how to do this.
The view will be better solution for me because it will present actual data otherwise i will have to insert new results of this procedure every day.
The difficulty is also that i don't know the number of columns and this value can change.Its based on view that i created.
Below is my code  :

```sql
create or replace procedure my_dataset.my_procedure(date_from string)

BEGIN 
declareTag_col string;
declare time string;

set time = data_od;
SET Tag_col = (
  SELECT 
    CONCAT('("', STRING_AGG(DISTINCT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(tag, "=", "_"), ":", "_"),"-",""), '", "'), '")')
  FROM `my_dataset.my_view`
);


EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
select * from
(
 SELECT
        REPLACE(REPLACE(tag, "=", "_"), ":", "_") AS tag,
        timestamp_seconds(600 * div(unix_seconds(timestamp)+300,600)) AS rounded_timestamp,
        AVG(value) AS value
    FROM `my_dataset.my_datatable`
    WHERE tag IN (select tag from `my_dataset.my_view`) AND timestamp >= %s 
    GROUP BY tag, rounded_timestamp
    ORDER BY rounded_timestamp
)

PIVOT(AVG(value) FOR tag IN %s)
""",time,Tag_col );
END
```

Comment: Can you improve your question by adding your current and expected results as per the [StackOverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Hi.The results are good for me and i just want to have view or table to share it to google data studio.Of course i can upload some screen with sample data if its necessary.

Comment: Hi. If you find the answer is helpful, please consider accepting & upvoting it as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56276633/why-is-big-query-saying-only-select-statements-are-allowed-in-view-queries-now) stackoverflow thread, DDL and DML queries cannot be saved as views. Your provided SQL script will throw an error `Only SELECT statements are allowed in view queries` as it is not a valid view.
If you want to save an arbitrary query for future use, you can use the [saved query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/saving-sharing-queries#creating_a_private_saved_query) instead.

For your other question, you can create a table from the query result by clicking the save results > save as BigQuery table. For more information refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#console).

Comment: Thanks for Your answer.
I found that its possible to save query result as a table but the problem is that i will have to do i manualy every day.
Maybe there is any other way to automatically get results from this script and save it to datatable ??

Comment: You can try [scheduling](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query) your query as per your requirement (ie. daily, hourly, weekly, monthly), which will automatically run the query at the specified time and save it to the specified table.